# JavaScript Calculator - How to get numbers into input field?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

So I have assigned all my numbers a class of numbers and all my operators a class of operators with ids specific to their operation. Every item is within a div tag.

Full data here: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jakewayne/L9mL4v3a/2/)

```
    <div class="number clear" id="clear"><h1>C</h1></div>
    <div class="number" id="entry"><input type="number"></div>
    <div class="number seven"><h1>7</h1></div>
    <div class="number eight"><h1>8</h1></div>
    <div class="number nine"><h1>9</h1></div>
    <div class="operate divide" id="divide"><h1>/</h1></div>
```

So the above is just a glimpse of the HTML. My CSS works perfectly fine but I'm struggling with the JavaScript. I've put in a for loop to pull from all the numbers in the HTML to do an addEventListener for onclick. I feel confident in the for loop but I could definitely be wrong. 
Right now I have the following:

```
let number = document.getElementsByClassName("number");
let operate = document.getElementsByClassName("operate");
let entry = document.getElementById("entry");
let clear = document.getElementById("clear");
let sub=document.getElementById("sub");
let multiply = document.getElementById("mul");
let divide = document.getElementById("divide");
let add = document.getElementById("plus");

for (let i=0; i<numbers.length; i++) {
  numbers[i].addEventListener("click", function(entry)){
    let inputValue = entry[0].innerHTML;
    let buttonValue = this.html;
    if (buttonValue === "C") {
     entry[0].innerHTML = "";
    } else {
      entry[0].innerHTML += buttonValue;
    }
  }
}

function (entry){

}
```

I know I need to run a function in the for loop but for the life of me I'm drawing blanks as to what to enter to push the values from the div into the entry field for the calculation. Right now if I click on any of the buttons nothing happens, clearly as there's no function. Any insight on how to adjust this to get something to populate would be appreciated.

Comment: You should really learn to debug. The console shows basic syntax errors. Fix those first.

Comment: Duly noted. Another set of eyes here really helped.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let numbers = document.getElementsByClassName("number");
let entry = document.getElementById("entry");

for (let i=0; i<numbers.length; i++) {
  numbers[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
    let buttonValue = this.textContent;
    if (buttonValue === "C") {
     entry.innerHTML = "0000";
    } else {
      entry.innerHTML = (entry.innerHTML+buttonValue).substr(-4);
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.number {
display:inline-table;
}
```

```html
<h1><div id="entry">0000</div></h1>
<div class="number"><h1>1</h1></div>
<div class="number"><h1>2</h1></div>
<div class="number"><h1>3</h1></div><br>

<div class="number"><h1>4</h1></div>
<div class="number"><h1>5</h1></div>
<div class="number"><h1>6</h1></div><br>

<div class="number"><h1>7</h1></div>
<div class="number"><h1>8</h1></div>
<div class="number"><h1>9</h1></div><br>

 <div class="number "><h1>C</h1></div>
```

You just mixed up some variable names and used non existent properties...

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues in your code:

1. Your event listener accepts a parameter called `entry`, which overwrites the `entry` variable in the outer scope. The first parameter of the event listener that you pass to `addEventListener` contains information about the click event (which you normally don't need). So remove the `entry` parameter from the event listener.
2. The value of `this` in an event listener is a reference to the element that you bound the event listener to. It won't have a property called `html`.
3. You declare a variable called `number`, but use a variable called `numbers`.
4. `numbers[i].addEventListener("click", function(entry)){` results in a syntax error. Remove the second `)` between parameter list and the function body.
5. `function (entry){}` results in a syntax error, because function statements require a name. Just remove it, it's superfluous.

That said, get some inspiration from the following code snippet:

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');
document.querySelectorAll('.number').forEach(function (button, index) {
  button.addEventListener('click', function () {
    input.value += index + 1;
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="number">
<button class="number">1</button>
<button class="number">2</button>
<button class="number">3</button>
<button class="number">4</button>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I have no idea what => functionality means in using vanilla JS  at the moment but your comments were helpful and hopefully I can glean some follow up on your code. Thanks!

Comment: I was using [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). They are just a shortcut and have the same functionality as the functions in the edited version.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Jonas in his answer, there are a bunch of issues in your current code - including some syntax issues. So I decided replace your event handler completely, and write it using jQuery - as it really comes in handy in such cases.

The event handler looks like this:

```
$(".number").on("click", function(event){
    var num = $(this).text();
  console.log(num);

  if(num != 'C') {
    var currentNumber = $("#entryNum").val();
    $("#entryNum").val(currentNumber.toString() + num.toString());
  } else {
    $("#entryNum").val('');
  }
});
```

The logic of the event handler remains quite similar to your original logic, but I have just simplified it using jQuery. Also, to allow for faster access to the input element, I gave it an ID `entryNum`:

```
<div class="number" id="entry"><input type="number" id="entryNum"></div>
```

Here's the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Nisarg0/L9mL4v3a/6/

Comment: Don't use jQuery if it's not tagged: *Unless another tag for a framework/library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected.*

Comment: @PeterMader Yup, I don't usually do this. In this particular case it seems the OP might not be familiar with jQuery, and may actually benefit from learning about it. Hence I attempted to introduce it.

Comment: I'm sure I'll learn more jQuery down the road so I appreciate seeing it. Just at the moment I can't use it. But thanks for showing what it would look like.

Answer (score 0):

Not certain about exact logic or expected result, though there are issue with selecting appropriate element and syntax errors

```
for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
  numbers[i].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
      // select the `<input>` child element of `entry` here, not `entry[0]`
      // and use `.value` property
      let inputValue = entry.querySelector("input").value;
      // you want `.textContent` here, not `.innerHTML`
      let buttonValue = this.textContent;
      if (buttonValue === "C") {
        entry.innerHTML = "";
      } else {
        entry.innerHTML += buttonValue;
      }   
  }) // include closing `)` at `.addEventListener()` call
}
```

Comment: Fixed the syntax errors that were pointed out. This doesn't actually push the number values into the input but it's logical and fixes some clear issues I had in the code so I appreciate it. Just doesn't fix it completely.

Answer (score 0):

I just implement Press and Clear function.

Learn and do it!

1.Add id for inputfield

```
<div class="number" id="entry"><input id="entryText" type="number"></div>
```

2.Do it!

```
let numbers = document.getElementsByClassName("number");
let entryText = document.getElementById("entryText");

for (let i=0; i<numbers.length; i++) {
    numbers[i].addEventListener("click", function(event){
    let buttonValue = event.toElement.innerText;
        if (buttonValue === "C") {
            entryText.value = "";
        } else {
            entryText.value += buttonValue;
        }
     });
}
```